# "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145

Tags: django, django-settings

Anytime I turn debug to false in my settings.py my site gives a server error. This is what my server shows and the site doesn't work again but when debug is true it works perfectly, I don't know what's wrong anyone with ideas on what might be going wrong

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

October 21, 2022 - 23:47:07

Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'dlcfogbomoso.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[21/Oct/2022 23:47:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145

[21/Oct/2022 23:54:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145
```

This is my settings.py file check it out for any error(s):

```
from pathlib import Path

import os

from decouple import config

from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent. Parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "Django-insecure-)=l1an%f&lb0+7z@!5l!ang_l!76ahs4eb-$((lt7vo1-mv0(*"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "myapp",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "dlcfogbomoso.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR, "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "dlcfogbomoso.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME":  "dlcfogbomoso",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "admin",
        "HOST": "localhost"
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator", 
  },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Not a definitive answer, but help. **too long for comment**

Go into your settings.py and add the code block below. This overrides the default Logging settings to output errors to the console even when debug is set as `False`. If you already have a LOGGING dict in the settings, just comment it out

**Note:** defaults are commented out, I just disabled the filters & disabled the existing default loggers

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    # 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{server_time}] {message}',
            'style': '{',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            #'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            #'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['django.server'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped to find the issue. I had to do `python manage.py collectstatic`